# PHP : How can i nest a product category array into multi dimensional array based on the parrent id?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, categories

I want to create a function which could return a multi dimensional array like category and its subcategory nested inside by giving an array which contains id ,category name and its parent id

Here is my array

```
<?php
          $category = array(  
                             [
                               'id'            => 1 ,
                               'name'          => "Main Category 1",
                               'parent_id'     => 0 ,
                               'subcategories' => array()

                             ],
                             [
                               'id'             => 2 ,
                               'name'           => "Sub Category of id 1",
                               'parent_id'      => 1,
                                'subcategories' => array()

                             ],
                              [
                               'id'            => 3 ,
                               'name'          => "Sub Category of id 2",
                               'parent_id'     => 2,
                               'subcategories' => array()

                             ],
                             [
                               'id'            => 4 ,
                               'name'          => "Another sub Category of id 2",
                               'parent_id'     => 2,
                               'subcategories' => array()

                             ],
                             [
                               'id'            => 5 ,
                               'name'          => "Another sub Category of id 1",
                               'parent_id'     => 1,
                               'subcategories' => array()
                             ],

                           ); ?>
```

and i want to transform this into like this

```
<?php 
        $category = array(

       [
        'id'            => 1 ,
        'name'          => "Main Category 1" ,
        'parent_id'     => 0 ,
        'subcategories' => array(
            [
                'id'            => 2 ,
                'name'          => "Sub Category of id 1" ,
                'parent_id'     => 1 ,
                'subcategories' => array(
                    [
                        'id'        => 3 ,
                        'name'      => "Sub Category of id 2" ,
                        'parent_id' => 2

                    ] ,
                    [
                        'id'        => 4 ,
                        'name'      => "Another sub Category of id 2" ,
                        'parent_id' => 2

                    ]
                )
            ] ,
            [
                'id'        => 5 ,
                'name'      => "Another sub Category of id 1" ,
                'parent_id' => 1
            ]
         )
      ]
); ?>
```

the parent_id reference the category id in the array

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use '&' operator correctly,

```
$categories = array();

//make associative array of $category with respective id as key

foreach($category as $val){
   $categories[$val['id']]= $val;
}

// fill in 'subcategories' while maintaining the references using '&' operator

foreach($categories as $key => &$val){
   if($val['parent_id']==0)
        continue;
   $categories[$val['parent_id']]['subcategories'][] = &$val;
}

var_dump($categories[1]);
```